# ServiceStack and concurrency

Tags: servicestack

We're evaluating ServiceStack and have found that all example hosts only allow a single request to be processed at a time.  If you add a Debug.WriteLine and Thread.Sleep to any entry point, this is easy to see.

I'm assuming we're either missing some setting or are missing a pretty big point with how ServiceStack should be used.

Thanks,
Ross

Comment: Which examples are you running (i.e. ASP.NET host or self-hosting) and how are you running it? i.e. is this with VS.NET WebDev server?

Comment: I tested the GetAllUsersService through ServiceStack.Examples.Host.Web (ASP.NET host) and GetFibonacciNumbersService through ServiceStack.Examples.Host.Console.  A colleague of mine saw the same behavior through both the windows service host and ASP.NET host.

Comment: Which ASP.NET host? VS.NET WebDev server or IIS? ServiceStack just works on top of ASP.NET's raw IHttpHandler's so the multi threaded web servers (i.e. IIS) takes care of setting up the worker threads.

Comment: Figured this out.  We were using the same browser with multiple tabs and/or windows to call the same service.  Once we used two different browsers (e.g. chrome + IE), we saw the expected concurrent request processing.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it :) Feel free to edit your question with your solution / work around. thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually was a mistake in how we were testing ServiceStack.  We were using the same browser but separate tabs/windows, which actually blocks itself from making concurrent requests.  Once using two different browsers (e.g. IE and Chrome), we were able to witnesse ServiceStack handling two requests at the same time.

Comment: Be sure to choose "Mark as Answer" :-)